# Parse Cloud with Swift PFIdResultBlock Error

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, parse-server, parse-cloud-code

```
 PFCloud.callFunctionInBackground("hello", withParameters: ["test":"tester"]) {
            (response: AnyObject?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                let responseString = response as? String
                print(responseString)
            } else {
                print(error!.description)
            }
        }
```

I am getting the error:

> Cannot convert value of type '(AnyObject?, NSError?) -> Void' to
>   expected argument type 'PFIdResultBlock?' (aka
>   'Optional<(Optional, Optional) -> ()>')

Even if I add  `as! PFIdResultBlock`, the error will not go away.

How can I go about fixing this?

I definitely appreciate your help on this one!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to specify the variable types while implementing the closure (Block in Objective-C) unlike Objective-C. You just need to change your code to the following:

```
PFCloud.callFunction(inBackground: "",
                         withParameters: ["": ""]) { (response, error) in
                            if error == nil {
                                let responseString = response as? String
                                print(responseString)
                            } else {
                                print(error?.localizedDescription)
                            }
}
```